# ASP Identity Core GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync expired

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1

I have set up an Identity Server 4 project in .NET Core 2.1, I have everything working but when I use the user manager to generate the reset password token, the token expires after 24 hours, can I change this so it's 48 hours?

My code to send the reset token looks like this:

```
var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

var callbackUrl = url.EmailConfirmationLink(user.Id, code, scheme);
```

My ConfigureServices looks like this:

```
   services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
        {
            config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Thanks :)

Comment: There is no specific tokens for those links that are included to email with links like "click me". You can change time period easy but for a whole application. `serviceCollection.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(
 x => x.TokenLifespan= ? );`  To achive more you will need to write your onw token provider https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-identity-token-providers and assign it to  `options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = MyProvider`

Comment: Hey I tied setting the DefaultEmailProvider to 48 hours and then assigning it to the   PasswordResetTokenProvider but it hasn't worked.I'll try setting it for all and see if that works. thanks :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Adding the following code to ConfigureServices() method in Startup.cs class should help you.

```
services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
    options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(2));
```

Default Token Lifespan is 24 hours (1 day). Please refer [github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Core/src/DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions.cs) and [TokenOptions](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/TokenOptions.cs)